# как правильно сформулировать проверку?

Tags: .htaccess

как правильно сформулировать проверку в htaccess?
мне нада сделать редірект на https с http не для всево сайта а только для 2 папок при етом в одной папке для одново файла тоже не делать редірект

Например

https:

http://site.com/test1/

http://site.com/test2/

но не для http://site.com/test2/some.php

все остальное http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
# если порт отличен от 443
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
# другое определение не https
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
# и если идет обращение к папке test1 или test2 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(test1|test2)/
# и если это не /test2/some.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test2/some.php
# то перейти на https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

UPD Скорее так:

```
# если порт равен 443
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
# другое определение https
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on 
# и если не идет обращение к папке test1 или test2 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(test1|test2)/ [OR]
# или если это /test2/some.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test2/some.php
# то перейти на http
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Comment: а можна как то зделать else для проверки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707916/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-else-%D0%B2-htaccess

Comment: @vov4ok, пишите второй блок условий, которые противоположны первому и в конце `RewriteRule` на вторую ссылку.

Comment: как то так?

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(test1|test2)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test2/some.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]

Comment: @vov4ok, в ответ дописал.

Comment: спасибо большое